# webstorm не видит файлы изображений, если подключать их через css

Tags: веб-программирование, webstorm

Подскажите, пожалуйста, может кто-то сталкивался...
 
В IDE webstorm подключаю изображения через background-image: url(/.....);
при этом в консоли ошибка "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)".
Вычитал, что нужно в настройках Вебшторма file/settings/derectories задать для папок с ресурсами параметр  Resource Root. Сделал - проблема сохранилась. Все пути прописаны верно, просто через HTML картинки подгружаются без  проблем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вы используете встроенный web server, то проблема в том, что путь в URL начинается со слэша. Такие ссылки браузер пытается ресолвить относительно корня вебсервера (простите за корявый русский). В случае встроенного вебсервера ссылка будет выглядеть как `http://localhost:63342/<путь к файлу относительно корня проекта>`. Но для встроенного вебсервера корень проекта не совпадает с document root сервера, URL всегда начинается с имени проекта: `http://localhost:63342/<имя проекта>/<путь к файлу относительно корня проекта>`, и попытка обращения непосредственно к `http://localhost:63342/` всегда вызывает ошибку 404. Т.е. вам нужно либо использовать в ссылках пути относительно текущего файла, либо пользоваться другим вебсервером. Еще одно возможное решение - переопределить `localhost` в `/etc/hosts` (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8988#comment=27-577559). см. комментарии в https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11949

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ. Нужно  просто переопределить localhost на папку проекта, я правильно Вас понял?

Comment: нужно в hosts прописать `127.0.0.1 имя_проекта`, и тогда можно будет ваш проект открывать на встроенном вебсервере, используя URL `имя_проекта:port` (заметьте - не `localhost:port`) см. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11949#comment=27-982492

Comment: есть, получилось )